# How to add "1" to a UILabel in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, addition

I need to add the value "1" onto whatever value is already in a UILabel view. For example, if the value of the UILabel were 2, I need to plus one to make it 3. How can I do this?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` has a handy method called `intValue`, which you can use like this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[label.text intValue]+1];
```

---

For your follow-up question, simply use an `if` statement:

```
if (label.tag == 1) {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[label.text intValue]+1];
}
```

or maybe you mean

```
if (something) {
    label.tag = 1;
} 

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[label.text intValue]+label.tag];
```

Comment: brilliant thanks! How can I set a if statement, where by I can set a tag and if the tag is "1" for example, then it would add the intValue 1 to the label?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 I used:

```
let currentLabelNumber: Int? = Int(label.text!)! + 1
      label.text = "\(currentlabelNumber!)"
```

I tried putting

```
let currentLabelNumber: Int? = Int(label.text!)! + 1
```

at the top of the function and reusing it but it didn't like that. Had to use both lines each time I wanted to increase the label value.

Hope this helps someone!